# Remove actionbar tabs padding in Android

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-tabs

[image: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/4/iy47.jpg/]

I have a problem with action bar tabs, I would like to remove the padding left or right in tabs.

I tried this style, but it didn't work :

```
<!-- indicator tab color -->
<style name="ActionBarTabBarStyle" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar.TabView">
   <item name="android:background">@drawable/tab_indicator_ab_example</item>
   <item name="android:paddingLeft">0dp</item>
   <item name="android:paddingRight">0dp</item>
</style>
```

Do you have any idea?

Comment: Which method of actionbar are you using. As in, via tabhost and tabmanager or something else? Are you able to show the code of which method you're using? 

Also try not to use themes until you've sorted out the problem, for example, your background could be causing the problem.

Comment: I have this problem also without any style defined. And no solution found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use custom layout..

```
    ActionBar actionBar;
    actionBar = getActivity().getActionBar();
    actionBar.setCustomView(R.layout.your_layout);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve the look your looking for by configuring the **'Widget.Sherlock.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse'**. Specifically **padding** and **minWidth** on the TabView and the backgroundStacked.

```
<style name="GPA_Sherlock_theme" parent="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar">        
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar.Solid.Example</item> 
    <item name="android:actionBarTabStyle">@style/ActionBarTabStyle.Example</item>
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar.Solid.Example</item> 
    <item name="actionBarTabStyle">@style/ActionBarTabStyle.Example</item>
</style>

 <style name="ActionBarTabStyle.Example" parent="@style/Widget.Sherlock.ActionBar.TabView">
     <item name="android:paddingLeft">0dp</item>        
     <item name="android:paddingRight">0dp</item>     
     <item name="android:minWidth">0dp</item> 
</style>

<style name="ActionBar.Solid.Example" parent="@style/Widget.Sherlock.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse"> 
     <item name="android:backgroundStacked">@drawable/ab_stacked_solid_example</item> 
     <item name="backgroundStacked">@drawable/ab_stacked_solid_example</item> 
</style>
```

Comment: The padding properties are the key.  Thanks.
The following is for users of the Holo Light theme.
`<style name="ActionBarTabStyle.HoloExample" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.TabView">  
<item name="android:paddingLeft">0dp</item>  
<item name="android:paddingRight">0dp</item>  
</style>`

Answer (score 3):

Add `app:tabPaddingStart="0dp"` and `app:tabPaddingEnd="0dp"` to TabLayout.
It works for me.

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
     android:id="@+id/tabs"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     app:tabGravity="fill"
     app:tabPaddingStart="0dp"
     app:tabPaddingEnd="0dp"
     app:tabIndicatorColor="#FF0000"
     app:tabMode="fixed" />
```

and add `xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"` to parent layout

Comment: It was the only solution working for me; as I was not using any ActionBar, TabHost, etc. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem goes from nonzero parent layouts padding.